# IonContent will not trigger scroll events if assigned a ref

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, scroll, react-hooks

I encountered the strangest problem today. My code (much has been stripped out) consists of basically the following:

```
const Element: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  const scrollRef = React.useRef<any>(null);

  .
  .
  .

  const rescrollTrigger = () => {
    setTimeout(() => { /* Retry for 10 seconds to scroll the content to match the stored value, unless the user has scrolled since then */
      const cb = (tries: number) => {
        if (tries > 100)
          return;

        if (!scrollRef.current) {
          setTimeout(cb, 100, [Number(tries) + 1]);
          return;
        }
        
        scrollRef.current.getScrollElement().then((element: any) => {
          var scrollHeight: any = window.sessionStorage.getItem(thisPath + "/scrollheight");
          var scrollTop: any = window.sessionStorage.getItem(thisPath + "/scrolltop");

          if (!scrollHeight || !scrollTop)
            return;

          scrollHeight = +scrollHeight;
          scrollTop = +scrollTop;

          if (element.scrollHeight == scrollHeight)
            scrollRef.current.scrollToPoint(0, scrollTop);
          else
            setTimeout(cb, 100, [Number(tries) + 1]);
        }).catch(() => {
          setTimeout(cb, 100, [Number(tries) + 1]);
        })
      };

      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        cb(1);
      });
    });
  };

  const saveScrollPosition = () => {
    console.log("saveScrollPosition", scrollRef.current);
    try {
      scrollRef.current.getScrollElement().then((element: any) => { 
        console.log("Saving scroll position");
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(thisPath + "/scrolltop", String(element.scrollTop));
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(thisPath + "/scrollheight", String(element.scrollHeight));
      });
    } catch (err) {console.log("Error saving scroll position", err)}
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen ref={scrollRef} scrollEvents={true} onIonScrollEnd={e => saveScrollPosition()}>

      .
      .
      .
}
```

I'm just trying to create a ref (in a hook) to the content instance so I can save and reset the scroll position as needed.

This code was working fine, but for some reason stopped triggering any scroll events if a ref is set on the content element. I've tried `onIonScroll` and `onIonScrollEnd`. Neither work if a ref is set. Removing the `ref={scrollRef}` starts triggering the scroll events. I'm using Ionic 6.12.2 and just recently upgraded from a prior version (I don't know what it was).

So my question is: Is this a bug in Ionic? Or if not, what should be done to fix the code? I've tried not setting a ref and just using the target returned from the scroll event, which allows me to save the position, but it doesn't preserve a reference to be able to reset the scroll position later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an Ionic bug. Ionic 6.12.3 allows the event to fire with a `ref` and the behavior is not reproducible.

Comment: What version @ionic/core does that correspond to?